# Bot isn't functioning as intended

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

Does someone know why my bot doesnt send 2nd reaction (B) and he doesn't send a message when user reacts?

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
            try {
                member.send(`Hello ${member}, welcome to the PotatoHost Server! 
        I want to help you and so my question is: Do you want to buy a server or do you need more informations first? \n
        A: I want to buy a server
        B: I need more informations first \n
        Please react to this message with A or B.`)
                .then(function (message) {
                    message.react("")
                    message.react("")
                    message.awaitReactions((reaction, user) => user.id == message.author.id && (reaction.emoji.name == '' || reaction.emoji.name == ''),
                        { max: 1 }).then(collected => {
                            if (collected.first().emoji.name == '') {
                                message.reply('Ok, so you want to buy a server. Let me recommend you to visit <#699374469977735208>.');
                                client.destroy();
                            }
                            else
                                message.reply('Ok, so you need more informations first. Let me recommend you to visit <#699374469977735208>.');
                        })
                });
            }
            catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
```

Error:

```
(node:29428) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordjsError: Request to use token, but token was unavailable to the client.
  at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\nicos\OneDrive\Documents\Discord Bots\PotatoHost Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:107:21)
```

Comment: According to your error, your bot token isn't working

Comment: Do you have `client.login('your token')` somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token was invalid so the bot could not start properly